# substring text node after first transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
  <element>
     <name>abc</name>
  </element>
  <element>
     <name>de</name>
  </element>
  <element>
     <name>fg</name>
  </element>
  <element>
     <name>ijkl</name>
  </element>
</foo>
```

I would like to concat all names, but get only first four characters from this value (not first four elements, but characters). So the output should look like

```
<something>abcd</something>
```

This is what I've got.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/foo">
   <something>
     <xsl:for-each select="element">
       <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
   </something>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My problem is that I don't know how to select only first four letters during XSLT processing. Is there a way to achieve this with XSLT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are interested not in first 4 chars from each `name`, but in first 4 chars
from all the concatenated names. So have to:

- Join text from all `name` elements.
- Take first 4 characters from the result.

You can do it this way:

```
<xsl:variable name="txt">
  <xsl:for-each select=".//name">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="substring($txt,1,4)"/>
```

In **XSLT 2** it would be easier:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(string-join(.//name, ''), 1, 4)"/>
```

so maybe you should move on to **XSLT 2**?

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(name, 1, 4)"/>
```

You can find more general info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_functions.asp).